# Replace foreach loop with linq query while sending list<string> data one by one to server using Active MQ

Tags: c#, linq, amq

I'm trying to replace this `for-each` loop with `Linq` query. This loop is killing the performance. `str` contains `list<string>`. I have to read one by one each string from `str` and encode it then I need to publish it to the server using `AMQ`.

```
foreach (var item in str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item);
        publisher.SendMessage(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: And what makes you think using linq would improve performance?

Comment: Your IO-bound operation here is `SendMessage()`. Converting to LINQ won't affect that.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using async

Comment: If you use LINQ , you'll get only 1 line of code ,that's all...After all , dude ,both linq and ur code loops through the entire collection :)

Comment: With Linq you'd just replace a list of strings with a collection of byte arrays.  The performance drain is in the calls to `SendMessage`.

Comment: I'm trying with linq and giving a try.

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545021/activemq-publish-messages-in-bulk-persistent-but-not-async

Comment: @Rajneesh when "*formatting mistakes*", be careful with indentation, you removed too much of it in the code block...

Comment: @peters You've asked for performance advice and ignored it from everyone. Simply searching 'foreach vs linq' will tell you how LINQ introduces overhead. `SendMessage()` is causing your drop in performance.

Comment: @peters `This loop is killing the performance`. It's what's happening *inside* the loop which is killing performance. If you want to iterate over a collection, you want to iterate over a collection, no escaping that - but that `SendMessage` must be the suspect.